# How to decompress .gzip file in S3, apply some sql filters, and store the result back as json in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So, I have hourly data coming in, in S3 - in .gz format. I intend to read all the .gz files in a particular S3 directory, together. Then, apply some sql filters on the data, and store the result as a json in a different S3 location.

Is this possible via a lambda function? Please share the code snippet if possible.

Or does this require some other architecture?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an ETL-process. I would advise you to use [AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/getting-started.html). This is a fully managed ETL service where you can write PySpark scripts. In there you can load data from S3, use the PySpark SQL API and write it in JSON back to a different S3 location.

Comment: Compression and SQL Filters kind of contradict real time. For larger data sets, Spark is really fast. There is the opportunity to use AWS EMR and run Apache Flink which is for streaming data and faster than Spark. Never used it myself though, so I can not ensure you that it works.